# Sorting a listbox relative to another

Tags: c#, sorting, listbox

I know that you can set up a ListBox to sort automatically.  Is there a way to "catch" the sorting so that when the ListBox swaps the position of two items so that I can do the same reordering on another list box?  I want sort one list box by by value but keep those values at the same relative index locations compared to another ListBox somewhere else.

I could write a routine to bubble sort the list so that I could make the changes myself, but it I am wondering if there is a more automated since I will likely have to do this at a few different places in the program.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `Sorted` property does not use the `IComparable` interface implementation just sorts based on the result of `ToString` of the items. But instead of setting the `Sorted` property, you can use a sorted data source (a `List<>`, for example).

Create a wrapper class for the items in the `ListBox` and implement the `IComparable<T>` interface on it. Populate a `List<>` with these `ListBoxItem` instances, then call the `Sort` method on the list. Thus you will able to dispatch the `CompareTo` calls.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private class ListBoxItem<T> : IComparable<ListBoxItem<T>>
        where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        private T item;

        internal ListBoxItem(T item)
        {
            this.item = item;
        }

        // this makes possible to cast a string to a ListBoxItem<string>, for example
        public static implicit operator ListBoxItem<T>(T item)
        {
            return new ListBoxItem<T>(item);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return item.ToString();
        }

        public int CompareTo(ListBoxItem<T> other)
        {                
            return item.CompareTo(other.item); // here you can catch the comparison
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var items = new List<ListBoxItem<string>> { "Banana", "Apple"};
        items.Sort();
        listBox1.DataSource = items;
    }
```